# How to display bootstrap carousel with multiple items in each slide?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3

Bootstrap Ver: 3.3.7

I want to display multiple images in one slide in bootstrap carousel.

Searched a lot and came across this site https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-display-bootstrap-carousel-with-three-post-in-each-slide/

In Example 2 problem is being resolved partially, i.e I can display multiple images in one slide, but the javascript code written in this website is cloning all the images and appending one image at a time in the end which is not the desired effect.

```
$(window).load(function() {
  $(".carousel .item").each(function() {
    var i = $(this).next();
    i.length || (i = $(this).siblings(":first")),
      i.children(":first-child").clone().appendTo($(this));

    for (var n = 0; n < 4; n++)(i = i.next()).length ||
      (i = $(this).siblings(":first")),
      i.children(":first-child").clone().appendTo($(this))
  })
});
```

My HTML code

```
<div id="carousel-commodities" class="carousel slide col-md-12"
  style="padding-left: 0; padding-right: 0;" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <a href="sourcing-solutions.html">
          <img src="assets/img/projects/corporate-gift.jpg"
            alt="Corporate Gifts">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h3>Corporate Gifts</h3>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <a href="sourcing-solutions.html">
          <img src="assets/img/projects/stationary-items.jpg"
            alt="Stationary Items">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h3>Stationary Items</h3>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <a href="sourcing-solutions.html">
          <img src="assets/img/projects/solar-panel.jpg"
            alt="Solar Panel">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h3>Solar Panel</h3>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <a href="sourcing-solutions.html">
          <img src="assets/img/projects/construction-machinary.jpg"
            alt="Construction Machinary">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h3>Construction Machinary</h3>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <a href="sourcing-solutions.html">
          <img src="assets/img/projects/power-tools.jpeg"
            alt="Power Tools">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h3>Power Tools</h3>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <a href="sourcing-solutions.html">
          <img src="assets/img/projects/paint-accessories.png"
            alt="Paint Accessories">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h3>Paint Accessories</h3>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <a href="sourcing-solutions.html">
          <img src="assets/img/projects/hardware-tools.jpg"
            alt="Hardware Tools">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h3>Hardware Tools</h3>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <a href="sourcing-solutions.html">
          <img src="assets/img/projects/fasteners-hardware.jpg"
            alt="Fasteners">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h3>Fasteners</h3>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <a href="sourcing-solutions.html">
          <img src="assets/img/projects/fabrics.jpg" alt="Fabrics">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h3>Fabrics</h3>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-commodities" role="button"
    data-slide="prev">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"
    aria-hidden="true"></span>
  <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-commodities" role="button"
    data-slide="next">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"
    aria-hidden="true"></span>
  <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Currently how it shows:
[image: current slider]

Desired result should be all images which are shown on screen at once should be in scrolled and new images should be shown in place.
In normal situation scroller would scroll out all images its currently showing and then show next set of images. What is happening currently is only one image is getting appended at the end when entire scroller scrolls the images.

Answer (score 0):

A nice workaround would be to add a transparent image for the slide, and then in the caption section, you may add a `div` that has multiple images inside.

```
<div class="item active">
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <a href="sourcing-solutions.html">
      <img src="transparent.png"
        alt="Nothing here">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <div class="groupImgs">
          <img src="image1" />
          <img src="image2" />
          <img src="image2" />
        </div>
        <h3>Corporate Gifts</h3>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

You may then style `groupImgs` the way you want to arrange the images internally.

Comment: Didn't work well. Attaching screenshot in my question how images are sliding as of current code. What is happening is when scroller starts it slides all images and only appends one new image to it at the end.

Comment: Well, my last shot would to be actually merge all the images you want to show on one slide in a single image. https://github.com/lukechilds/merge-images should help you with that. It might have some performance issues though.

Comment: Not a good idea. As end user might ask to change an image from the group of images which is combined again we have to re-combine all images.

Comment: Yes, the merge happens dynamically in runtime!

Comment: github.com/lukechilds/merge-images - Seems to be a great library, haven't used it, but would like to experiment on this in some other project. Thanks man.